# $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ with a nonstandard topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ the topology on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ generated by the collection of lines $y= 2x+k$ with $k\in \Bbb R$ (in the sense that the line $\{y=2x+k\}$ is a basic element for $\tau$) .

Find $\tau_1, \tau_2$ such that $(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R,\tau)$ is homeomorphic to $(\Bbb R, \tau_1) \times (\Bbb R,\tau_2)$.

EDIT: Corrected spelling. Sorry for the inconvenience.

---

The problem is that I can't write rigorously what I think on this:

Since an open set can always be written as a union of basics elements, open sets in this "line-topology" are bands, or union of bands. Looking at the Y-axis (as an example) the basic element $(a,b)$ in the **standard** topology is reflected in the band $y=2x+k$, with $k\in (a,b)$ and vice versa. So, $\tau_2$ should be the standard topology.

On the other side, I know that if $f\colon X \to Y$ is a continuous map, then $X$ is homeomorphic to the graph of $f$. Applying this to the exercise, $\tau_1$ should be the trivial topology, $\tau_1 = \{ \emptyset, \Bbb R\}$

So, as always, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ is trivial then $A \times B$ is homeomorphic to $B$ (since $A$ is topologically just a point). So $\tau_1$ is definitely not trivial.

Comment: Try $\tau_1$ be the usual, $\tau_2$ be the discrete topology of the real line. Hope it works, if not reverse them :) What do you mean by the word "defined": How do you define a topology by a collection of lines, do you assume these lines are a basis for the open sets, or alternatively, do you assume that these lines have their usual topology (and then you consider the strongest topology on the plane consistent with this requirement)? My first hint applies to the latter case. In the former case (which you apparently mean), try $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ be the discrete and indiscrete topologies.

Comment: @Mirko by defined I meant "generated". I edited the post. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

For each $k\in\Bbb R$ let $L_k$ be the line whose equation is $y=2x+k$; I interpret the statement that $\tau$ is defined by these sets to mean that $\{L_k:k\in\Bbb R\}$ is a base for $\tau$. Thus, the set of points on **any** family of these lines is open in $\tau$, not just bands. That is, for any $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, $\bigcup_{k\in A}L_k\in\tau$.

Now consider one of these basic open sets, say $L_k$. Does it have any open subsets? Only $\varnothing$ and $L_k$ itself, because $L_k\cap L_j=\varnothing$ when $j\ne k$. Thus, the relative topology on $L_k$ induced by $\tau$ is the indiscrete (trivial) topology. Now there’s obvious bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $L_k$, given by the map

$$f_k:\Bbb R\to L_k:x\mapsto\langle x,2x+k\rangle\;;$$

this map will be a homeomorphism if and only if we give $\Bbb R$ the indiscrete topology $\tau_2=\{\varnothing,\Bbb R\}$ as well. Thus, as a subspace of $\langle\Bbb R\times\Bbb R,\tau\rangle$ each $L_k$ is a copy of $\langle\Bbb R,\tau_2\rangle$, and $\langle\Bbb R\times\Bbb R,\tau\rangle$ ‘looks like’ a bunch of copies of $\langle\Bbb R,\tau_2\rangle$ side by side. How many copies? One for each $k\in\Bbb R$. This gives us a map from $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ to the space $\langle\Bbb R\times\Bbb R,\tau\rangle$ that sends the pair $\langle k,x\rangle$ to the point $f_k(x)$ on the line $L_x$:

$$h:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\times\Bbb R:\langle k,x\rangle\mapsto f_k(x)=\langle x,2x+k\rangle\;.$$

Note that $h$ takes $\{k\}\times\Bbb R$ to $L_k$.

- Show that $h$ is a bijection.
- Find a topology $\tau_1$ on $\Bbb R$ so that $h$ is a homeomorphism from $\langle\Bbb R,\tau_1\rangle\times\langle\Bbb R,\tau_2\rangle$ to $\langle\Bbb R\times\Bbb R,\tau\rangle$.